# While loop until find a word

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have only 2 columns in sql server. The first column (name) starts with the name "abc" in the first line and it ends in the 8th line (Endabc).
I need to have second red color column:
(while the first column starts with "abc" until the word "Endab"c, update second column and put 'abc' in all those lines).
How can i do this?
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: You need a column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question pre-supposes an ordering column.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So there is no ordering unless that information is in a column.

You can use a conditional sum to identify the groups and then spread the values.  Assuming that the ends are not really needed (because a new value starts right away):

```sql
select t.*,
       max(case when name not like 'End%' then name end) over (partition by grp) as imputed_name
from (select t.*,
             count(case when name not like 'End%' then name end) over (order by <ordering col>) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```

[Here is a db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf863ec9e521a56404c4f5cb118484cc).

Comment: Thanks for your help and reply.
i changed my parameter according to your code but i have error. could you please tell me what i did wrong?
Thanks.
select [Test3].*,
       max(case when [name] not like 'End%' then [name] end) over (partition by grp) as imputed_name
from (select [Test3].*,
             sum(case when [name] not like 'End%' then [name] end) over (order by SecondColumn) as grp
      from .[dbo].[Test3]
     ) [Test3]

Comment: @arash6657 . . . I fixed a mistake in the query and added a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks but there is still a problem. I added a screen shot to the main question that you can see it. Could you please correct it? Thanks

Comment: @arash6657 . . . I added a db<>fiddle that is quite close to your data, showing that it works.  If your data is different, you should not change an answered question.  You should ask a *new* question.  Also, I removed that edit to this answer.  And do not see an edit on the question.

Comment: Thanks for the database in Fiddle and your helpful solution.
i didn't mean to change the answered question, i just added a picture from my database that you can see it. 
Best regards